# how to sum up number in front of string

Tags: c, string, sum

How do I sum up numbers in front of strings? For example, I have input:

```
15 humpbacks
3 killer whales
2 sperm whales
19 belugas
2 humpbacks
2 sperm whales
7 killer whales
4 pygmy right whales
7 humpbacks
```

Then I want to sum up the numbers and be like this:

```
24 humpbacks
10 killer whales
4 sperm whales
19 belugas
4 pygmy right whales
```

Comment: omg the last phrase is epic

Comment: which language? I just see 'string' tagged

Comment: guys, no use in downvoting someone with 1 point. Ahmad: use a regular expression, but first decide what language to use and change your tag

Comment: sorry, it's c language

Comment: I downvote questions, not people. There's plenty of point downvoting bad questions.

Comment: `regular expression`, or `strtok` with `atoi`

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You need to implement a data structure that allows you to map a string with an integer variable. In a loop, you will read a line, parse it, and populate your map. When you parse a line, you would take the string and look it up in your map. If the entry does not exist, create it and initialize the integer variable to 0. If it does exist obtain the variable. In either case, add the number found in the line to the variable. Continue this until you have no more input. At the end of the program, iterate over your map and print out the string and the associated value.